# ionic 4 capacitor not working with ionic/angular i need to add Event

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

In ionic 4, capacitor ionic/angular is not working.
I need to add an Event and subscribe to it to track login and logout time

Does anyone know of a more detailed documentation for capacitor plugin with implementation example similar to the ionic documentation.

I have checked [the capacitor homepage](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/) but the documentation is scarce and lists only a few plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event at angular has been depracated, so you need to create you own service to achieve the event and to do so , do as below:

Create event service.
In the EventService.ts:

```
export class EventService {
            private dataObserved = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
            currentEvent = this.dataObserved.asObservable();
            constructo(){}
            
            publish(param):void {
              this.dataObserved.next(param);
            }
}
```

For publishing the event from example page1:

```
constructor(public eventService:EventService){}
        updatePost(){
        this.eventService.publish('post:updated');
        // or 
        this.eventService.publish({name: 'postupdate', value: 'value you need to pass'});
}
```

In page 2:

```
constructor(public eventService:EventService){
          this.eventService.currentEvent.subscribe(data=>{
         // here you can get the data or do whatever you want or data.name or data.value
        
        });
}
```